# Enable Go Back button in Windows 11 After 10 Days

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

Is there a registry setting that will allow me to re-enable the 'Go Back' button in Windows 11 after 10 days for going back to Windows 10?

Comment: No. You are too late. `windows.old` will have been deleted.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ahh I didn't realize that's how it worked. If I would have backed up that folder I wonder if it would have worked.

Comment: "Is there a registry setting that will allow me to re-enable the 'Go Back' button in Windows 11 after 10 days for going back to Windows 10?" - **YES** However, it must be changed, before the 10 days has expired otherwise `Windows.old` would have already been deleted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Is there a registry setting that will allow me to re-enable the 'Go Back' button in Windows 11 after 10 days for going back to Windows 10?

There absolutely is a registry key that can be used to extend the period to 60 days. However, it must be changed before `Windows.old` is deleted, in the original 10 day timeframe.  If `Windows.old` is deleted, then it's not possible, to revert back to the previous version.

You can verify if it's possible by running the following in an elevated PowerShell prompt:

```
DISM /Online /Get-OSUninstallWindow
```

If you receive `Error 1168 – Element not found` it means the system cannot be rolled back to the previous version.  If the system can be rolled back then it will display the number of days the rollback period is set to.

You can change this value anywhere from 2 to 60 by running the following command in an elevated PowerShell prompt:

```
DISM /Online /Set-OSUninstallWindow /Value:60
```

Source: [DISM operating system uninstall command-line options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-uninstallos-command-line-options?view=windows-11)

These commands work on Windows 10 20H2+ and Windows 11 21H2+

The registry key associated with this feature can be found at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\UninstallWindow
```

You can set the value of `UninstallWindow` to a decimal value anywhere between 2 and 60.

Answer (score 3):

Once the 10 days have passed, to downgrade back to Windows 10 will
require a clean install, and you will lose all your data.

You will need to get it from Microsoft at
[Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

Comment: Or do an image backup first, with (e.g.) Macrium Reflect Free and just restore the image. Save any files you have changed in the meantime before the restore.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain what's wrong with this answer? It's quite short, but it's to the point and accurate.

Comment: @gronostaj: It's worst than you think - there were 2 downvoters here (and two upvoters).

Comment: @harrymc I've actually checked before typing that comment and it was +0/-1, so the other one must have downvoted despite my comment. I have no words.

Comment: @gronostaj: I have stopped reacting to those things - no point.

Comment: @gronostaj It wasn’t me. :)

Comment: @gronostaj - unexplained downvotes are just a fact of life on Stack Exchange. I've had quite a few. The way the system works is that votes by 'the community' make 'good' answers rise up, and 'bad' ones sink down. There is no requirement to explain, although that might be helpful, and some parts of SE actually ask downvoters not to explain, as that can lead to 'comment wars'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I didn't know about the comment wars thing. IMO if an answer is plain wrong and unsalvageable, sure - just downvote it to hell. But otherwise I'd rather see that answer improved and remove my downvote and I don't think I can expect someone to improve it without telling them what needs improving.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey And this answer… I just don't know what could be wrong with it. Either I'm missing something and a comment would open my eyes, or the downvoter is incorrect and they would benefit from being corrected, or they just downvote everything that's not up to their standards of perfection. Anyway, someone would benefit from the explanatory comment. I'm not aware of any SU policy on this.

Comment: @gronostaj - comment by staff member at English Language and Usage SE: "People have asked us for years to require a reason for downvoting. And it's not something we have any plans to do. It's not up to the voter to explain their choice to vote ... The reason people tend to want to discredit downvotes is that they are uncomfortable... and I understand and share that feeling... but I do not advocate that everyone be required to cough up an explanation in order to vote on a post. "

Comment: @gronostaj "Once the 10 days have passed, to downgrade back to Windows 10 will require a clean install," - although this answer is technically not incorrect it lacks essential details (compare to ramhound's answer). It doesn't add any significant information in regards to the other answers I suppose this is the reason for the downvotes is ...  but I can only speculate here. I have similar problems with my own answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can save a Windows install as an image file easily if you have an external drive big enough, and a 250 GB USB drive costs around $25 these days. There are a number of free software apps, including Macrium Reflect, EaseUS Todo, AOMEI Backupper, and others. I make an image weekly, and before I make a change that I might want to back away from. You have to make a 'rescue' USB stick or CD that you would boot the PC from if you want to restore an image. It's not hard.