# Revert from Windows 11 using a Macrium image

Tags: backup, downgrade, windows-11-upgrade

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this. My PC bought in March 2022 is showing in Windows 10 Update as 'eligible for Windows 11'. So far I have resisted the temptation, as I have a lot of stuff that I fear may be broken if I switch.

I know I can revert in within 10 days. If, before upgrading to Windows 11, I make a backup image of the disk, say with Macrium Reflect, and restore it later than 10 days after, am I likely to find the old Windows 10 install is now unlicensed?

Comment: Why don’t you just increase the amount of time you have to decide by increasing the value stored in the appropriate registry key. **Windows installations don’t become unlicensed, even if it did, you could instantly reactivate the installation with a single click.** Your worried about a non-issue[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1722953/enable-go-back-button-in-windows-11-after-10-days/1722965#1722965)

Comment: I have been running Windows 11 Pro for nearly 2 years now - 18 months in Production. Nothing is going wrong here.

Comment: @John - I have a whole bunch of personal developer stuff, like Perl scripts, Git Bash, plus a WSL2 setup (Debian 11) all just the way I want them. Also Hyper-V and VMWare VMs. I'd hate to find them failing, especially in subtle ways.

Comment: If login is local, i.e., not using a Microsoft account, then I can see no way that restoring from a disk image would fail. However, I do not know if MS accounts would cause issues. BTW, be aware that MS plans to revoke keys of old disk images in Secure Boot: https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2023/05/10/bootkit-zero-day-fix-is-this-microsofts-most-cautious-patch-ever/